# How to use Laravel data in Vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components

File Structure

Inside App.blade.php

I used vue router to pull the components.

I have a normal variable like `$users` which I can access in blade file like `{{$users}}` . Now how can I access the same data in my component?

Comment: where your component exist ? in `.php` file or in `.js` or `.vue` file ?

Answer (score 1):

If your `$users` variable is a collection you can use:

```
<my-component :users="{!! $users->toJson() !!}"></my-component>
```

Comment: This will definitely work only when if this component put inside `.php` file.

Comment: I assume that being the case here as `App.blade.php` is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is php server side scripting language which compiled before front end Javascript and Vue is javascript.

So to get value of php variable in js take this value in a input text field as json

```
<input type="hidden" id="users" value="{{json_encode($users)}}">
```

And inside vuejs inside `mount()` update your `data's`, `users` element

```
mounted(){
   var users = document.querySelector("#users").value;
   users = JSON.pars(users);
   this.users = users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I am using props, Look at my example :

I have a QuestionComponent and I want to sent $quetion_set->id valuable to the file so that In blade file I sent a props ,

> ```
>  <question question_set_id="{{$question_set->id}}"/>
> ```

In the QuestionComponent I set props :   `props:['question_set_id'],` then used it in the component like this : `this.question_set_id`

If you want to pass array data then you should use JSON.parse function to reache your data , for example :

> ```
>    JSON.parse(this.question_set_id)['id']
> ```